# Border-bottom in codename one

Tags: user-interface, border, codenameone

Is it possible to have bottom border only without creating 9-piece image border? Is there possible workaround, say, drawing a line in Codename One Designer?

Comment: It would be extremely useful if I can set colour instead of image in image border, or particular parts (i.e., left, right, top and bottom) of line border instead of searching for workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in code where a line border can only be applied to one of the sides however building the UI to describe that visually (and the related data) proved difficult.

A better approach would be to use an image background rather than a border (define the border as empty) and set its behavior to tile bottom.

Codename One also has a 3 piece image border which is designed for things like the iOS back buttons and not so much for the underline.

Comment: Would be very grateful if you can provide me with an example. I found `Border.createLineBorder()` and `container.getStyle().setBorder()` only which I believe do not provide a way to get desired behaviour.

Comment: See Border.createCompoundBorder() you can use empty for all sides and then line border for the bottom. Notice that you should almost never use getStyle() and instead use getUnselectedStyle(), getSelectedStyle() etc...

Comment: For future reference, I used following code to create bottom border `Border border = Border.createCompoundBorder(null, Border.createLineBorder(1, 0x858585), null, null);`.

Comment: May I advise to put notes in border help section so that developers know that compound border exist?

Comment: We've added those but we don't normally recommend it... We recommend using the image border or tiled image at the bottom.